# angularjs with ui-router, states getting confused

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 states; **viewOrder** and **saveOrder**. Their definition looks like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('viewOrder', {
    url: "/orders/:orderNumber",
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/view.html',
    controller: 'ViewOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});

$stateProvider.state('saveOrder', {
    url: '/orders/save?orderNumber',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/save/index.html',
    controller: 'SaveOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});
```

When I use `$state.go('saveOrder')` it gets confused and thinks I am trying to view an order and believes the **/save** is the actual order number.
Is there a way I can keep my URL like it is, but stop the confusion?

Comment: You want to hide parameters from url?

Comment: no, I don't want the URLs to get confused with each other

Comment: Question is little bit not clear. Please explain in detail

Comment: Change the urls to have different words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I have added the url param in saveOrder with a colon..

```
$stateProvider.state('viewOrder', {
    url: "/orders/:orderNumber",
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/view.html',
    controller: 'ViewOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});

$stateProvider.state('saveOrder', {
    url: '/orders/save/:orderNumber',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/save/index.html',
    controller: 'SaveOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $state.go('saveOrder') is changing without parameter.

change like this `$state.go("saveOrder", { "orderNumber": 123});`

```
$stateProvider.state('viewOrder', {
    url: "/orders/:orderNumber",
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/view.html',
    controller: 'ViewOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});

$stateProvider.state('saveOrder', {
    url: '/orders/save/:orderNumber',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/orders/save/index.html',
    controller: 'SaveOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});
```